# Is DataRow thread safe? How to update a single datarow in a datatable using multiple threads? - .net 2.0

Tags: .net, multithreading, datarow, thread-safety

I want to update a single datarow in a datatable using multiple threads. Is this actually possible?

I've written the following code implementing a simple multi-threading to update a single datarow. I get different results each time. Why is it so?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static DataTable dtMain;
    private static string threadMsg = string.Empty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread[] thArr = new Thread[5];
        dtMain = new DataTable();
        dtMain.Columns.Add("SNo");
        DataRow dRow;
        dRow = dtMain.NewRow();
        dRow["SNo"] = 5;
        dtMain.Rows.Add(dRow);
        dtMain.AcceptChanges();
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(delegate { dtUpdate(); });
        thArr[0] = new Thread(ts);
        thArr[1] = new Thread(ts);
        thArr[2] = new Thread(ts);
        thArr[3] = new Thread(ts);
        thArr[4] = new Thread(ts);

        thArr[0].Start();
        thArr[1].Start();
        thArr[2].Start();
        thArr[3].Start();
        thArr[4].Start();

        while (!WaitTillAllThreadsStopped(thArr))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        foreach (Thread thread in thArr)
        {
            if (thread != null && thread.IsAlive)
            {
                thread.Abort();
            }
        }
        dgvMain.DataSource = dtMain;

    }

    private void dtUpdate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                dtMain.Rows[0][0] = Convert.ToInt32(dtMain.Rows[0][0]) + 1;
                dtMain.AcceptChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool WaitTillAllThreadsStopped(Thread[] threads)
    {
        foreach (Thread thread in threads)
        {
            if (thread != null && thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Thank you

NLV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx):

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

So since you are updating `DataRow` and `DataTable` objects you will need to use some form of synchronization to guarantee your code is thread safe.

By the way, you should also never call `Thread.Sleep` or do a busy loop in your UI thread. Otherwise the UI will be completely unresponsive until all threads have finished executing. Instead you should have some kind of progress bar (or just a spinner) displayed on your UI, which is optionally updated by events from  your threads. The [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class is specifically designed to make this job easier for you, so you may want to consider using it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the documentation for the type or member specifies otherwise:

- Static members are thread safe.
- Instance members are *not* thread safe.

Comment: Disagree. Static members are accessible by any number of threads at once. This opens up the risk of races and deadlocks.  The **inverse** is true. If you instance a new object per thread, they are naturally thread safe (by sheer force of encapsulation).

Comment: @code4life This is the standard set by the Framework classes that is part of how they are implemented. It does not mean when creating a new type to achieve this standard you need to add appropriate locking.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are truly wrong. You can write a simple test app to prove this to yourself.  This incidentally, was one of the earliest lessons that I learned, working with the .NET Framework, that almost anything static in it, is not inherently thread-fenced.  And the common truth of all threading, is that static members are vulnerable to races and deadlocks. Any simple test will reveal this.

Comment: If you mean your own type's static members are not thread safe automatically: correct. You have to implement the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices#recommendations-for-class-libraries). The .NET Framework – except where documented – *does* follow these guidelines (and I assume Core, but I've not checked). For third party libraries you need to check. For you own code you need to do the work.